# Removing outer quotes from list encoded as string in python

Tags: python, string, list, quotes

I am doing some data cleaning from a file I read with pandas. I will illustrate the problem I have with a simple example.

I have the following string:

```
a = '["1","2","3"]'
```

And I would like to turn it into a list. Therefore, I need to get rid of the outer quotes.

Final result should be:

```
a = ["1","2","3"]
```

So that I can access the list using indexes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Didn't find that post before. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

You can make a workaround using `list` comprehension  like :

```
>>> [x.strip('\"') for x in a.strip("[]").split(",")]
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: you can simply do: ```output_list = json.loads(input_string)``` just by using json module.